# postgresql split_part() returning only unique substrings separated by a delimiter?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, split, distinct

I know that split_part() can separate concatenated string consisting of string elements separated by a delimiter, like this:

```
SELECT split_part(col, ',', 1) AS col1
     , split_part(col, ',', 2) AS col2
     , split_part(col, ',', 3) AS col3
     , split_part(col, ',', 4) AS col4
FROM   tbl;
```

However, I have a situation where elements inside concatenated string are redundant, i.e. there are duplicate elements.
How can I retrieve only unique string elements (substrings), i.e. without duplication of same substrings?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. You want to split to columns, so how do you want to handle these duplicates?

Comment: I think my description is more than precise - If you have only read it, you would know what I want with duplicate values.
I want to split a string column with delimited values into separate columns, but without values duplication, only unique values.

Comment: Sample date might clear up some ambiguity in your question. What if the unique elements are less than 4? What do you expect for e.g. the input `1,1,1,1,1` or `1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4` or `1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5`?

Answer (score 2):

I would convert the column into an array with distinct elements:

```
select elements[1] as col1, 
       elements[2] as col2, 
       elements[3] as col3, 
       elements[4] as col4
from (
  select array(select distinct on (e) e
               from unnest(string_to_array(col, ',')) with ordinality as c(e,idx) 
               order by e,idx)  as elements
  from tbl
) t
```

---

If you need to do that a lot, a function would make this a bit more readable:

```
create function distinct_elements(p_input text, p_delim text)
  returns text[]
as
$$  
  select array(select distinct on (e) e
               from unnest(string_to_array(p_input, p_delim)) with ordinality as c(e,idx) 
               order by e,idx);
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then use it like this:

```
select elements[1] as col1, 
       elements[2] as col2, 
       elements[3] as col3, 
       elements[4] as col4
from (
  select distinct_elements(col, ',') as elements
  from tbl
) t;
```

---

But a much better approach would be to normalize your data model and don't store comma delimited values in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

If I am following this correctly, you could split to string to a derived table first, grab the distinct values, and then pivot to columns. We need to keep track of the original position of each value, for which `with ordinality` comes handy:

```
select t.*, x.*
from tbl t
cross join lateral (
    select 
        max(colx) filter(where rn = 1) col1,
        max(colx) filter(where rn = 2) col2,
        max(colx) filter(where rn = 3) col3,
        max(colx) filter(where rn = 4) col4
    from (
        select colx, row_number() over(partition by colx order by min(n)) rn
        from regexp_split_to_table(t.col, ',') with ordinality x(colx, n)
        group by colx
    ) x
) x
```

When there are duplicates, only the first appearance of each value is retained.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I retrieve only unique string elements (substrings), i.e. without duplication of same substrings?

If this is what you want, I don't see why you want four columns.  Just use:

```
select distinct part
from regexp_split_to_table(col, ',') part;
```

I am interpreting your question as removing duplicates *across* rows as well as *within* a given row.